# Excel VBA code to execute when worksheet loaded

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am not at all an expert in these matters, but I have an excel sheet that i wish for to be auto-generated and sent by email on daily basis. Now the values in the Excel are updated from DB so that's taken care of. I have the worksheet on my desktop. I thought of using Task Scheduler in windows vista but not sure neither if that's the right thing to be doing.

I need the sheet to be opened...updated...then updated version sent by email to xxxx@xxx
Any idea or hints how to do this?
The code I've got off the net and works with sending the email is:

```
Sub Mail_ActiveSheet()
'Working in 97-2010
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim I As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

'Copy the sheet to a new workbook
ActiveSheet.Copy
Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
With Destwb
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2010, we exit the sub when your answer is
        'NO in the security dialog that you only see  when you copy
        'an sheet from a xlsm file with macro's disabled.
        If Sourcewb.Name = .Name Then
            With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = True
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With
            MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
        End If
    End If
End With

'    'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
'    With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
'        .Cells.Copy
'        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'        .Cells(1).Select
'    End With
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = "Part of " & Sourcewb.Name & " " _
             & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, _
            FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    On Error Resume Next
    For I = 1 To 3
        .SendMail "dsdsdsd@hotmail.com", _
                  "dsds,dsd, dsdsdsds report"
        If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit For
    Next I
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
End With

'Delete the file you have send
Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is all doable, I would recommend using a vbs via task scheduler. Two comments/queries (1) When does your workbook get updated from the database - does this happen outside this code? (2) `Sendmail` will raise a Outlook warning. How are you handling this - manual clicking or a program like *clickyes* ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the code below via a text editor such as `NotePad` as a [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) , something like "myscript.vbs". *Note this is not VBA*
2. Use the instructions from [How to use the Windows Task Scheduler](http://www.iopus.com/guides/winscheduler.htm) to schedule the vbs
3. If your email is delivered via `Outlook` use [clickyes](http://www.contextmagic.com/express-clickyes/) to bypass the outlook warning.(If you confirm this I would add further automation to the code to force the send/recieve

Please change the path to your desktop file here
`strWB = "C:\temp\test.xls"`

Some of the code appeared redundant, ie saving and killing the file is irrelevant as `SendMail` works directly (whereas using Outlook would require adding the saved attachment). The file version didn't appear to add value either

```
    Dim objExcel
    Dim objOutlook
    Dim objWB
    Dim objws
    Dim strWB
    Dim strWB2
    'Change file path to be emailed
    strWB = "C:\temp\test.xls"
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strWB)
    'Change sheet index as needed
    Set objws = objWB.Sheets(1)
    objws.Copy
    With objExcel.ActiveWorkbook
        .SendMail "brt@notmyemail.net.au", "test"
        .Close False
    End With
    objWB.Close False
    With objExcel
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .Quit
    End With
```

Comment: Also, enabling the setting "Refresh data when opening" is probably a good idea. See the screenshot http://i44.tinypic.com/2hq8j7r.png

Comment: @Gebb thx for the suggestion. As per my query against the original question its not clear to me when or how the database updated to Excel is effected. I think we need more detail